# Python Flask: search MySQL start with an alphabet

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create an API that allow a user to search in MySQL table with user input.

For an example, user input is 'PA', it will search in a table for a Stock starting with 'PA'.

Prior that, I have tested a search starting with 'P', and it works. However, if I change `sg='P'` and `curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'"%sg+'%')` unable to get Stock start with P and `return 'Error: unable to fetch items'`

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
def KLSEstock(Stock):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='vin',passwd='xxx',db='vinudb$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    curs = db.cursor()
    sg ='P%'
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'"%sg)
        c = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': c})
```

Question is `curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'"%sg)` and `sg ='P%'` compare with `curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'"%sg+'%')` and `sg ='P'`is the same, but why the former is able to query from database but the later not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an error in logic as those two statements will produce different queries.

For the first version:

```
sg = 'PA%'
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'" % sg)
# -- will execute
# SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE 'PA%'
```

For the second version

```
sg = 'PA'
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'"%sg+'%')
# -- will execute --
# SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE 'PA'%
# note that the % is outside of the quotes!
```

You can observe this behavior by checking the strings like this:

```
sg = 'PA'
st = "SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock LIKE '%s'"%sg+'%'
print st
```

Because `%` has higher precedence than `+`.  In order to get the behavior you want you can either change your format string or append `%` before you use execute.  Any of these will work:

```
sg = 'PA'
# use %% to insert a % into the format string
curs.execute("select * from klse where stock like '%s%%'" % sg)
# force precedence of `+` over `%` using parentheses
curs.execute("select * from klse where stock like '%s'" % (sg + '%',))
# append the `%` before you call `execute`
sg += '%'
curs.execute("select * from klse where stock like '%s'" % sg)
```

In any case, if sg is from user input, make 100% sure it is escaped, otherwise you will leave yourself open to a SQL injection attack.  There are lots of good libraries (including [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/views/)!) that [help you out with this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/#easy-querying).

> Be sure to use question marks when building SQL statements, as done in 
>   the example above. Otherwise, your app will be vulnerable to SQL 
>   injection when you use string formatting to build SQL statements. See 
>   Using SQLite 3 with Flask for more.

Comment: @I use only GET, is it safe?

Comment: Nope.  Still have to escape `sg`.  Otherwise someone can input `'; drop table klse; --'` and have it drop your table.

Comment: `curs.execute("select * from klse where stock like '%s%%'" % sg)` when I cahnge to `curs.execute("select * from klse where stock like '%s%%'" , sg)`,it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: You have to use the `%` if you want python to insert `sg` into the format string for you.  If you want to use Flask’s escaping, you have to use `.like()`  or `.startswith`.  http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/queries/#querying-records